# How to pass a formula as "x variable" in Altair chart?

Tags: interactive, altair

I have a pandas DF with two quantitative variables A and B.

I would like to build a graph as described in the example gallery (https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/selection_histogram.html#selection-histogram).

No problem on the scatter plot.
But for the bar chart, I would like to represent the average difference between A and B (formula should be : sum(A)/sum(B)-1) only for the brush selection.

Is there a way to pass a formula in the x argument in the code below ?

```
chart1 = alt.Chart(df).mark_bar().encode(
    #y='Origin:N',
    #color='Origin:N',
    x='sum(A)/sum(B)-1'
).transform_filter(
    brush
)
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [Aggregate Transform](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/transform/aggregate.html) and [Calculate Transform](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/transform/calculate.html)

It would look something like this:

```python
chart = alt.Chart(df).transform_filter(
    brush
).transform_aggregate(
    sum_A = 'sum(A)',
    sum_B = 'sum(B)',
    groupby=['Origin']
).transform_calculate(
    diff = 'datum.sum_A / datum.sum_B - 1'
).mark_bar().encode(
    y='Origin:N',
    color='Origin:N',
    x='diff:Q'
)
```

In general the order of transforms does matter: for example, by putting the `transform_filter` first, the sums will be computed on the filtered values.

Comment: Just perfect ! Thanks a lot